# Changing structure of ToC in LyX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I worked out how to have unnumbered subsubsections appear in my toc.

It looks like this:

[image]

However, I want it to look like this:
[image]

Hence: subsubsections appear, but separated via '|' in a block, only the chapter's or the section's page number is given.

Has anyone an idea how I could implement this in LyX? Thank you very much!

Comment: In LyX, I  don't know, but for the LaTeX code behind, it can be done with the `\titlecontents*` command fom the `titletoc` package (a component of `titlesec`).

Comment: Great, it worked– thanks!

Comment: @Suza could you please write an answer that gives the steps in LyX for how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by Bernhard, one can use the \titlecontents* command.
I therefore added the following to the document's LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[0em]{\small}{\thecontentslabel. }{}{}[\ |\ ][]
```

Shout out to Bernhard for pointing to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think in `Document>Settings` there is a `Numbering & TOC` tab where you can change the default settings.

Comment: Yes, I used it to enable the result presented above. Thank you though. ;)